# Godaddy question mark and variable name hide php get

Tags: php, forms, get, form-submit

I have been trying for the past few days to get a Godaddy hosted server to hide the question mark and the variable name in the url automatically (ie. mysite.com/?id=5 >>> mysite.com/5) using Rewrite Rules in the .htaccess file.

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [P]
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it the Godaddy servers?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you try the following? `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)*$ ./index.php?id=$1`

Comment: It doesn't do anything, is there a way I can find out if it is running or not?

Comment: Enter some junk value into your .htaccess e.g. foo bar, sakjnaskljdnas any keyword not recognized by htaccess and visit your URL. If it is working, you should get a 500 Error.

Comment: It's running becuase I get a 500 error

Comment: Cool okay. Then replace the whole of your .htaccess with mine, and try abc.com/page/123

Comment: It loads index.php!  Is that a good sign?

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following into your .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^index/(\d+)*$ ./index.php?id=$1
```

You can learn more about clean urls here: http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls